# PHP json_decode returning NULL on invalid JSON

Tags: php, json

**UPDATED SOLUTION BELOW**

Here is the supposed json:

```
a: 14: {
s: 9: "rating_id";s: 24: "rwp_rating_5aafe3e80b03d";s: 14: "rating_post_id";i: 3293;s: 16: "rating_review_id";s: 32: "14855d71ef49debd6f9493c13b1bf84b";s: 12: "rating_score";a: 1: {
    i: 0;d: 5;
}
s: 14: "rating_user_id";i: 2;s: 16: "rating_user_name";s: 0: "";s: 17: "rating_user_email";s: 0: "";s: 12: "rating_title";s: 0: "";s: 14: "rating_comment";s: 11: "dsfusof9832";s: 13: "rating_images";a: 0: {}
s: 11: "rating_date";i: 1521476584;s: 13: "rating_status";s: 7: "pending";s: 15: "rating_verified";b: 0;s: 15: "rating_template";s: 26: "rwp_template_5a1d7fcb9457e";
}
```

However, when I checked it with JSONLint, it does not validate. I receive the error:

Error: Parse error on line 1:
a: 14: {    s: 9: "rat
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

I need to extract the value of "rating_comment"

Can someone help make this valid JSON or help to extract the value of "rating_comment"?

**SOLUTION**

I did not know that this was serialized string and NOT JSON.  Thank you for pointing that out to me.  I will use unserialize to get the data I need. :)

Comment: It's not a JSON string, it is a [serialized](http://php.net/serialize) string.

Comment: Thank you!  I need to learn to tell the difference. :)

Comment: @osakagreg use `unserialize` function

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`unserialize()`](https://php.net/unserialize) to get your value. But your string is not a valid serialized string. You have to remove extra spaces, and linebreaks (the string cannot be changed like JSON).

```
$serial='a:14:{s:9:"rating_id";s:24:"rwp_rating_5aafe3e80b03d";s:14:"rating_post_id";i:3293;s:16:"rating_review_id";s:32:"14855d71ef49debd6f9493c13b1bf84b";s:12:"rating_score";a:1:{i:0;d:5;}s:14:"rating_user_id";i:2;s:16:"rating_user_name";s:0:"";s:17:"rating_user_email";s:0:"";s:12:"rating_title";s:0:"";s:14:"rating_comment";s:11:"dsfusof9832";s:13:"rating_images";a:0:{}s:11:"rating_date";i:1521476584;s:13:"rating_status";s:7:"pending";s:15:"rating_verified";b:0;s:15:"rating_template";s:26:"rwp_template_5a1d7fcb9457e";}';

$obj=unserialize($serial);
echo $obj['rating_comment'];
```

Outputs:

```
dsfusof9832
```

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Machavity. Should I delete this one?

Comment: I would. We have a ton of questions talking about serialize